# How to add an image to the left of the RadioButton in RadioGroup

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, radio-button, radio-group

How to add an image to the left of the RadioButton in RadioGroup?

I tried DrawableLeft‚ it makes the picture too big. I couldn't find a way to zoom out. scaleX and ScaleY also did not help (.

There are a lot of programs out there that I want, but I can't do that.

What I want:
[image]

Please help‚ thank you!

Comment: I know I'm stating the obvious but you can try controlling the drawable size. The other options include having multiple linear layouts but it becomes a pain to preserve the functionality of the radiogroup

Comment: Can you give an example? Please

Answer (score 0):

This is one example but even though it would give you the required layout the radioGroup property is lost since it will stop managing checked states of nested buttons. You'll have to handle the radio button checked stated programmatically which is a lot of work.

DrawableLeft and then adjusting the image size manually in your vector files would be the best solution in my opinion.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```